# Programming in Binary

Tags: binary, binaryfiles

I've been learning the basis of binary programming. I've got it all sorted out with bytes are 8 digits of binary. What the bytes mean like capital letters and that. But now I want to learn some simple code so I have two questions:

1 - Are there any good tutorials for programming in binary. I've just found a few scraps that I'm piecing together and now it makes sense.

2 - How can I program in binary using Windows 10 64 bit. I know I can't just write in a text editor to a .exe file because it doesn't work. I've heard of hex editors but when searching I've seen hex editors with hex code when I want binary code. Is there a binary editor.

Comment: What do you mean by "programming in binary"? That you want to enter the ones and zeroes into memory manually? Or do you mean that you want to use another language, and manipulate single bits of a value? Or something else completely?

Comment: What does "programming in binary" mean - you want to write Assembly directly as 1s and 0s? If that's what you're asking, it's similar to saying "I'd like to clean all floors on Earth using nothing but a toothbrush" You can't find a less efficient way to accomplish the task...

Comment: Well. I'd just like to know more in depth knowledge and I've gone pretty low level already so I'd like to know the basics of binary. As for what I want. I'd like to enter the zeros and one's so that I can make a program I can run such as a console window.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there and I doubt anyone here can. I could point you to some resources on Assembly, but even for that you need specifics. It's not just "write a program" you need to code for a specific CPU because different CPUs support different instruction sets. If you want to learn programming, I'd suggest learning a high level language first. I can't think of a programming task worse than writing directly in machine code.

Comment: FYI, also when you mention "that's hex not binary" shows you have a lot to learn. Hex, decimal, binary, octal, base64, etc. are just ways of expressing the same info differently. Hex a = decimal 10 = binary 1010. They're all the same.

Comment: There's a reason that assembly languages were invented, and low-level languages, and high-level languages. Programming by setting bits is extremely hard, error-prone, and really tedious. And that's only to make simple DOS-type programs that doesn't use any higher level things like BIOS (to continue in DOS times) not to mention the whole Windows API. So to answer your question in short: You can't. A little longer answer: You can, but it's going to take weeks (or even months) to even make the simplest text-only hello-world program.

Comment: Well it certainly makes sense as an experiment, but as I wrote in my aswer below, I don’t think it’s possible with this level of knowlegde. Gather some experience points with assembly and try again :–)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, “binary programming” means what could be better described as *writing object code by hand*. In other words, directly writing code in the language of the CPU. It has little to do with binary (or hex) number notation, at least directly.

Writing object code directly, without the aid of a compiler (a tool for translating from a higher-level language down to the “CPU language”), is quite hard and I don’t think it’s possible to do given your current level of knowledge. Go learn C or assembly, take a look at the generated object code, try to make sense of it, and then you may start thinking about writing “binary”.

Which, by the way, has little practical application outside of fun. Not that fun wouldn’t be reason enough, but you certainly don’t have to know how to write object code by hand if you just want to be a programmer, even a low-level one (one that does work close to the HW).

Comment: you have a sadistic definition of "fun" :)

Comment: I think it is important to mention as well that there is no universal "object code." Different CPUs speak different "dialects". For example, an x86 is very different than an ARM processor, or an i64, or even x64 in some cases. Each supports different "words" used to perform different tasks. A high level language like C handles all of the translation during compilation.

Comment: I never said anywhere I haven't learned C or Assembly. I said I want to go lower level programming.

Comment: Also, I'd accept this answer but it still doesn't answer any of my questions on how to actually run binary code.

Comment: Because the question stated like this does not really make sense, sorry.